# Ubuntu 20.04 screens use same scaling

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, scaling

I have a dual monitor setup with a dell xps 13 and a 30 inch dell 2560 x 1600.  For this to work (and it was fine before I upgraded to 20.04) the laptop needs to be scaled to 200% whilst the big monitor stays at 100%. However when I adjust the scaling it is applied to both screens rendering one unusable. I've tried with gnome, xorg, wayland, kde, etc. Problem is the same for all display managers. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: The methods described at [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Font_size_for_high_resolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui) work for me with high resolution screens. Maybe one of them is better with two monitors  --The first method (with `gnome-tweak-tool`) should be combined with separate scaling for some programs, for example Firefox and Thunderbird. See [this link](https://fedoramagazine.org/how-to-get-firefox-looking-right-on-a-high-dpi-display-and-fedora/) for Firefox. There is a corresponding link for Thunderbird. You can use e.g. 1.6 instead of 2.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but playing with Fonts is not really what I was looking for. It's hard to believe that scaling just isn't working with dual monitors when it works fine with Windows and it worked fine with the previous version of Ubuntu - surely there must be a solution for this.  Is this not a really common problem for us Ubuntu users?

Comment: I hope that someone who knows will see your question so that you will get help. -- And when your problem is solved, please remember to share your solution here.